# How to add a xscrollbar to Text widget in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

According to [this](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm) source: both x and y scrollbars can be added to the Text() widget of tkinter. The codes which work in procedural method are:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

frame = Frame(master, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)

frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

xscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL)
xscrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

text = Text(frame, wrap=NONE, bd=0,
        xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set,
        yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)

text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

xscrollbar.config(command=text.xview)
yscrollbar.config(command=text.yview)

frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

However, i choose the class method and wrote the below codes, according to the below codes y scrollbar works but x scrollbar doesn't work. Why doesn't x scrollbar work in this example?

```
import tkinter as tk


 class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.x_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=self, orient="horizontal")
        self.x_scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="w, e")

        self.y_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(master=self)
        self.y_scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="n, s")

        self.text = tk.Text(master=self, width=100, height=25, bg="black", fg="white", wrap=None)
        self.text.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="n, s, e, w")

        self.configure_widgets()
        self.pack()

    def configure_widgets(self):
        self.text.configure(xscrollcommand=self.x_scrollbar.set, yscrollcommand=self.y_scrollbar.set)
        self.x_scrollbar.config(command=self.text.xview)
        self.y_scrollbar.config(command=self.text.yview)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is not the scrollbar code but the assignment of `None` in wrap config of your textbox.

Change

```
wrap=None
```

To

```
wrap='none'
```

on an unrelated note

change `sticky="n, s, e, w"` to `sticky="nsew"` the commas mean nothing in a quote here. And your other stickys should be `"we"` and `"ns"`

You might have been trying to do the tkinter CONSTANTS version of the stick. That would look like this:  `sticky=(N, S, E, W)`. However because you did not import `*` this will not work. You could import each constant from tkinter individually but in this case its best to use `sticky="nsew"` instead.

Just for reference here is a list of the `'nsew'` constants you get when you import `*` from `tkinter`

```
N='n'
S='s'
W='w'
E='e'
NW='nw'
SW='sw'
NE='ne'
SE='se'
NS='ns'
EW='ew'
NSEW='nsew'
```

Comment: Glad to help. If this answer worked for you please consider selecting the check box next to my answer.

Comment: Yes, website waited 10 minutes to give approval.

Comment: Ah. I guess I answered to fast for the websites liking lol. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you again. :)